# What heroku Procfile for parse server

Tags: node.js, heroku, procfile, parse-server

Completely new to heroku, profiles and node.js. I'm running Parse Server hosted on Heroku and I'm trying to get [kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue) running in order to do scheduled jobs.

To achieve that I need to add a worker. And to do that, I need a Procfile. But I don't know what to put in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work fine :

```
web: node index.js
worker: node queue.js
```

Where `index.js` is the index.js file of parse server and I have my queue related code in `queue.js`. Hope it'll help !